# Drawing a $K_{8}$ on a genus 2(or sphere with two handles, or double torus)

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I know, that $K_{8}$ can be drawn on genus 2, but I can't draw it and I can't find any articles and examples, illustrating, how it can be done. Can anybody help me? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

[image: the drawing]
Every pair of dots of the same color is joined together (so every of the two pairs of grey circles with colored dots represents a handle).

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer indeed fully solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. If something has to be clarified, I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

[image: K_8 embedded in a double-torus]

The double torus is formed by identifying opposite edges of an octagon.