# How would one draw an embedding of $K_8$ on a 2-holed torus with no edges crossing?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I understand that a 2-holed torus can be formed by connecting sides of an octagon, as shown in the included image, and the completely connected graph with 8 vertices, $K_8$, can be embedded into the 2-holed torus, such that there are no crossings of edges. I am trying to use the octagon diagram and imagining the connections to be like the sides of a Pac-Man maze to draw the graph of $K_8$, however, I have found much difficulty connecting opposite sides of the graph, where there isn't a convenient portal. How would one complete the embedding? I haven't found any such diagrams, at least that I understood.

[image: The folding of an octagon]

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496850/drawing-a-k-8-on-a-genus-2or-sphere-with-two-handles-or-double-torus/2497283) thread can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[image: eight mutually neighbouring regions on a double torus]

(The two objects are identical. The surface of each is divided into eight regions, each bordering each of the others at least once.)

Credit to Simon Bexfield.

[image: Here is the dual of the 8-colouring shown above, presented in an octagon as requested.]

It isn't beautiful or symmetrical. I expect it could be improved a little.

And it has 30 edges. To reduce it to K_8, remove one of the green edges and one of the blue edges - your choices.

Comment: These are beautiful (+1), but would you mind adding a 2D diagram showing the K8 in an octagon with sides identified?